# Why is '%0A' appearing in my url when making a request

Tags: python-3.x

I'm attempting to download a file using requests, I have a master file which I extract a specific link and add that portion to the base url. When I print out the result it looks fine and exactly how it should be delivered. However, upon inspection it seems the server can't authorise the link as %0A is added before the extracted portion. How do I remove it as it doesn't appear in print.

```
Base_Url = https://testing.net/watch/'

Vid = data.split('1920x1080=')[1] #Where the portion starts
Vid = Vid.split('#')[0] #Where the portion ends

#data is a file with all of the links, lets assume the extracted portion is = master.m3u8

Video_M3u8 = str(Base_Url) + str(Vid).rstrip() #Adding the base url with the extracted portion
```

What I would like produced:

```
https://testing.net/watch/master.m3u8
```

However, when I intercept the traffic, it appears as:

```
https://testing.net/watch/%0Amaster.m3u8
```

This causes it to appear as an invalid url, as I said earlier, when I print the result of Video_M3u8 it appears as how I want, its when its being forwarded by python requests it changes.

Comment: %0A is an HTML entites... It's a "Line feed" (char 10).

Comment: Is there a way to prevent it from being added?

Comment: The linefeed is added inside your Python  --  Can you  print out your variables in a console or shell?  This will clearly display newlines ..

Comment: From the example, it seems that the \n is at the end of Base_Url.. I do not know Python syntax: is the example code correct? there is apex at the end of watch/' ...Missing initial apex, or is this the strange character?
Maybe you can also try to use str(Base_Url).rstrip() + str(Vid) ... rstrip() should remove a trailing newline

Comment: It seems python is producing this result: 'https://testing.net/watch/' followed by a second line 'master.m3u8'

Comment: is there anyway to get around the line feed as I need to concatenate the two parts together?

Comment: Sorry, I do not use Python.. But have you tried to write: 
Base_Url = 'https://testing.net/watch/' 
? If it give the same result, leaving the Line Feed at the end of Base_Url, try to use: 
Video_M3u8 = str(Base_Url).rstrip() + str(Vid).rstrip()

Comment: What's strange is that I use two different ways to do this, I have an audio url and a video url, with the audio url I managed to use re.search to extract the portion and it works fine, but it doesn't seem to work with the video url, it seems my search returns none